# Difficult time controlling loops in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a sheet of employee with over 20,000 rows.  All their SSN’s are in column Y.  There are an unknown # of lines for each person.  Column L has month #’s 1-12 in it .  Data begins on row 8.  I set my DataRow to 8 at the start.  File is sorted by SSN’s.  What I am trying to do is write a “Y” in columns AJ thru AU of the Output tab to represent if the employee has a row with that month in column L.  And that works.

My issue is that I need to loop through each employee, keeping track of each record on the “Orig Data”  tab for one line count, but know when the SSN changes so I can increment the OutputRow when writing to the Output tab.  I am comfortable with most of the VBA constructs.

But I am having a logic problem.  Using the Do While or Do Until and comparing SSN’s between lines only gets the records for one employee and then ends.  And If I use a For Each or For Next, I still have to compare SSN’s between records to determine when they change.

This is the relevant code.  I shortened the list of Case statements for brevity.  I don’t really need code syntax help.  (Well I know nothing about arrays.)  I am just stuck in narrow way of designing this.  I am sure there is a better way that I am not considering.  What are your suggestions?

```
Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Orig Data").Range("A" & DataRow + 1)) = True
    Do While Sheets("Orig Data").Range("Y" & DataRow) = Sheets("Orig Data").Range("Y" & DataRow - 1)

        Select Case Range("L" & DataRow).Value
            Case "1"
                Sheets("Output").Range("AJ" & OutputRow) = "Y"

            Case "2"
                Sheets("Output").Range("AK" & OutputRow) = "Y"

            Case "3"
                Sheets("Output").Range("AL" & OutputRow) = "Y"

        End Select
        DataRow = DataRow + 1
    Loop 'until changes person
    DataRow = DataRow + 1
    OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
Loop 'until Blank
```

My intent is to write the record to the Output tab which has the 12 columns appended to the end of it.  I should end up with one record for each employee.  We will be running multiple files through this process when complete as part of a one time provider interface.

Answer (score 0):

After bangin' my head, and walking away for awhile, I was able to get ti to work.  I just couldn't see the forest for the trees.  I just had to restructure a bit and rely on an IF statement to do some of the checking.  For those who are really detail oriented, yes there are column changes in the Case statements because I found out one column will not be in the final files.  And this is what it looks like:

```
                Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Orig Data").Range("A" & DataRow + 1)) = True

                    Select Case Range("K" & DataRow).Value
                        Case "1"
                            Sheets("Output").Range("AI" & OutputRow) = "Y"

                        Case "2"
                            Sheets("Output").Range("AJ" & OutputRow) = "Y"

                        Case "3"
                            Sheets("Output").Range("AK" & OutputRow) = "Y"    
                    End Select

                        If Sheets("Orig Data").Range("Y" & DataRow) <> Sheets("Orig Data").Range("Y" & DataRow + 1) Then
                            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
                            DataRow = DataRow + 1
                            Worksheets("Orig Data").Range("A" & DataRow & ":AH" & DataRow).Copy Worksheets("Output") _
                            .Range("A" & OutputRow & ":AH" & OutputRow)
                        Else
                            DataRow = DataRow + 1
                            If IsEmpty(Sheets("Orig Data").Range("A" & DataRow + 1)) = True Then
                                MsgBox "Done"
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                        End If
                    Loop
```